# Website & Web Application

Tags: manual-testing

what is the difference between the Website and Web application? For eg: facebook, twitter, myntra, onlinesbi etc...this are all website are web application.

Comment: Already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694922/whats-the-difference-between-a-web-site-and-a-web-application

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a duplicate of a question on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694922/whats-the-difference-between-a-web-site-and-a-web-application

Comment: That might seem like it, but that's actually not an off-topic reason, even if they were the same question. And although the content is the same (actually, that one is fleshed out much more thoroughly) this is tagged with [tag:manual-testing] which makes me assume Mahesh is looking at this from a testing perspective instead of a terminology perspective. If anything, it's a close for "unclear what you're asking" because how it relates to testing isn't clear in the question.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is in an individual's perception. It all depends on what you think. Many would say that Facebook is a web application, whereas others would say it is a website.

For example services like the ATM software, payment gateway, email service can all be thought of a web application. But if you really get into the depth you will see that they have webpages built which execute in web browsers and run on technology that is used for developing and executing web services, which by definition according to me makes them a website.

So, the true answer is IT DEPENDS on how you look at it... ;)

Answer (score 1):

> what is the difference between the Website and Web application?

From a QA point of view, there is no difference.

Some application development tools/environments have these as different choices, depending on the tasks involved in the project (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I dare to differ. Websites are mainly about content and web-applications about user specific functionallity. Testing a website would focus on can the user find what he needs, where a web-application focuses on can the user do what he needs.

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal - I've never seen testing be about anything other than whether a user can do what's needed. Was the Amazon of 10 years ago a web site or a web application? Did anyone care as long as they could get what they wanted there?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the website is what the user sees and can interact with in the browser.

The web application is the thing that handles those interactions and tells the browser what to display.

The user doesn't interact with the application directly, only with the website.

Comment: I understand somewhat...can you elaborate......

Answer (score 0):

A very basic explanation

1. Website is just a web page where most of the time testing will be of broken links and broken images and more if SEO is being processed on/for that website
2. Web application is a application where there has to be more work from the testing point of view for example applying various types of testing

Comment: This is really too simplistic for this site - we tend to prefer more substantive answers that include reasons for the decisions and definitions.